# PCI Device Mapped Region for low physical memory

Tags: memory, memory-management, linux-kernel, dma, pci

[image: Memory Map]

I have been reading about how the PCI subsystem gets configured from Bootup, BIOS involvement and mapping of device addresses i.e the BAR's into system Memory.

1. From the diagram above I am assuming that the address space is physical 4GB RAM with 4GB physical addresses. So, As can be seen above 3GB the device memory is mapped. What happens to this memory on 2GB physical RAM addresses.
2. If suppose my assumption is wrong and the above map shows virtual address for a 32 bit system. Then how is the device memory mapped to physical addresses for DMA. Is the mapping permanent (non swappable and changeable).

Please help me understand this concept.

Answer (score 0):

1. If I understand your question, nothing different happens on a 2GB system. There will simply be a "hole" in the physical address space between 2GB and 3GB; that is, there simply won't be a hardware device decoding the addresses here. But otherwise there is no significant difference with respect to PCI devices: they will still be assigned space in the region above 3GB.

   It's important to note that the map you show above (physical address space) doesn't necessarily stop at 4GB (since about 1995). Most modern x86 processors have more than 32 address bits. This is why you now often get systems with more than 4GB RAM. And there may be additional holes in the address space above 4GB too.

   Actually *using* the RAM above 4GB requires either the processor's 64-bit mode or PAE (Physical Address Extension) which offers a way to address more than 4GB of physical space in 32-bit mode. [There is also PSE-36 {Page Size Extension} but that's much less commonly used.]
2. The map you're showing above is specific to physical address space. The x86 virtual address space, (when the processor is operating in 32-bit mode) is 4GB in size, but it does not have all the reserved areas in your diagram. Indeed, the layout of the virtual address space is totally dependent on and determined by the operating system. The *usual* way that it's configured in linux reserves the part of the virtual address space below the 3GB line for user-mode, and the area above 3GB for kernel-mode. However, this configuration can be changed via the kernel config.

Mapping of the physical address space into virtual address space is managed by the operating system kernel on a page by page basis. A virtual page may be directed either to system RAM or to a PCI device. And note that the page size can vary too, depending on how the processor and page tables are configured.